# Cómo insertar datos de una tabla a otra?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Buenas tardes comunidad.

Estoy tratando de insertar datos de una tabla que se encuentra en una base de datos diferente a otra pero tomo una concatenación de un dato clob, por lo cual no me deja insertar. Hice la consulta aparte y me dejo de marcar lo del clob pero al momento de querer insertar otra vez me marco error. Alguien me podría decir como podría hacer para corregir el error. Gracias de antemano. Todo esto es en ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

```
Error SQL: ORA-22992: no se pueden utilizar los localizadores LOB seleccionados en las tablas remotas
22992. 00000 -  "cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"
```

Consulto el select solo y si me marca, ya dentro del insert me manda lo anterior dicho.

```
INSERT INTO FST136_GUIASINVESDOC(
    FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE, FST136_NAMETIPOEXPEDIENTE, FST136_FLD2MASTER, FST136_FLD3HOUSE, FST136_FLD1REGISTRO, FST136_RUTADOC
)
(
    select
    'EXP-001' AS FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE, d.name TIPO,
    fld2 MASTER, fld3 HOUSE, c.fld1 REGSIRO,
    dbms_lob.substr@INVESDOC(
        (
            SELECT
            replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( replace(
                d.info, '"01.01"|"\\Srv-invest', '\192.170.1.103'),
                '"01.01"|"\\srv-invest','\192.170.1.103'),
                '"01.01"|"\',''),
                '"01.01"|"\\192.170.1.104',''),
                '"01.01"|"',''),
                '"|3|1|3|0|0',''),
                '"|3|2|3|0|0',''
            ) || '\' || b.name || '\' || a.loc
            FROM dual@INVESDOC
        ), 4000, 1
    ) AS info
    from rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR@INVESDOC a
    inner join rinves11.A20SF@INVESDOC c on a.extid2 = c.fdrid
    inner join rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR@INVESDOC b on a.volid  = b.id
    inner join rinves11.IVOLREPHDR@INVESDOC d on b.repid = d.id
    where  fld2 = '157-80676385'
);
```

Comment: Un diseño incongruente; a menos que estes seguro que ningún valor `d.info` sobrepasa los 4000 bytes vas a tener pérdida de información, y si es el caso ¿por qué usar un LOB -que es difícil de manipular- pudiendo ser VARCHAR2 o LONG?. Por otro lado, tal vez encuentres menos inconvenientes usando un cursor implícito en lugar de pretender hacerlo todo en un SELECT. En lugar de `dbms_lob.substr()` ¿intentaste con `to_clob()`?

Comment: la tabla ya estaba hecha y el dato fue registrado como clob como menciono el dato viene así ""01.01"|"\\192.170.1.103\aaa_2010\2010_Entradas"|3|1|3|0|0" y yo solo ocupo la ruta de 192 en adelante . Es necesaria para lo que me piden por lo cual trato de convertirla a varchar o una forma para que la tabla remota pueda jalar la información(no puedo cambiar el campo clob en la base de datos por permisos etc) to_clob no lo he checado ya que las consultas que he hecho me sigue marcando error para insertarlo en otra tabla de base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

La [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/working-with-LOBs.html#GUID-BA662EA5-4955-4582-B12E-3312FE4B1D6A) dice que hay toda una serie de usos **no soportados** para LOBs (clob, blob) desde bases de datos remotas (vía dblink). Este es uno de ellos.

Claro que va a funcionar el select, el amigo le dice a la BD tráeme x, y, z,... y te los trae.
El problema aquí es que debe armar un resultSet y manipularlo para insertarlo en la tabla local. Ahí Oracle ya no es feliz y no lo puede hacer.

Dependiendo de tus datos, podrías tratar de transformar los LOB en varchar2 de 4000 bytes y ahí sí insertarlos.

Comment: dbms_lob.substr@INVESDOC (informacion) FROM dual@INVESDOC), 4000, 1) AS info Una pregunta no con eso ya se convirtio en varchar , igual leí que no se podia y habia serie de pasos para medio hacer algo, pero igual me queda la duda de la linea que te coloque, o como convertir a varchar porque ya los registros estan ahi y no puedo eliminarlos. Solo trae una ruta para mi como °°||000" nombre °°||, algo asi pero necesito ese dato "nombre"

Comment: @Jaz Se supone, pero no es evidente que estés procesando todo del lado de la BD remota por como armaste la consulta. Yo buscaría que la subconsulta sobre la BD remota haga de una vez el substr y el resultado sea la salida de ese substr. Con eso, **creo** que se ejecutaría del lado de la BD remota y obtendrías el varchar y _tal vez_ funcionaría

Comment: Al final del [5.1.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/distributed-LOBs.html#GUID-BD5EB0E6-FAA0-42A0-A25B-FC8C64867A40) dice: *"DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR devuelve un LOB"*.

Comment: @Sal es verdad! Gracias! Me quedé con lo que dice la documentación del método y no revisé bien en ese enlace

Comment: @Sal entonces solo se puede usar como longitud y no como varchar? es lo que alcance a notar con ese tema